# Reading GitHub File Names in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am new to Azure Devops.

I have setup a GitHub repository which has bunch of xml files.
I have setup an Azure Pipeline which copies the files from GitHub repo and publish it as artifacts. This is then fed as input to another pipeline for performing some actions.

I want to know how to read the names of the GitHub files that I am pulling and I want to publish another artifact which lists only the file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter and print whole XML files in your Azure agent directories including  Build.SourcesDirectory where code is downloaded

Here is the one Bash sample

```
- task: Bash@3
  name:  findyamls
  displayName: findyamls
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline' 
    workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
    script: | 
      find "." -type f -name "*.yaml"  >> $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/filenames.txt
      cat $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/filenames.txt
```

Comment: Thank you,
I had to change the working directory from "Build.SourcesDirectory" to "Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory" and it works.
Now when I run the pipeline, I can see the file names listed in the console output.
How can publish these file names as an artifact ?

Comment: Do you want to publish particular files or a list that has particular file names?

Comment: @Adityan Please see the updated solution. And if it's solution for you make sure upvote it